# Gap between top margin and figure

Tags: graphics

I am getting this ugly gap between subfigures and the top margin. I'm really puzzled because when it's only one figure it's nicely aligned. How can I align my subfigures to the top margin?

I'm using koma-script book, but the problem persists when I change to book.

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,british]{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=17cm,paperheight=23cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.2cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.1cm,rmargin=1.3cm,footskip=1cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\centering{}\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}%
\caption{Single figure nicely aligned}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
\centering%
\subfloat[First subfigure]{\rule{0.49\textwidth}{5cm}}%
\hfill%
\subfloat[Second subfigure]{\rule{0.49\textwidth}{5cm}}%
\caption{Group of figures with ugly gap on top}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's done on purpose by `subfig`, which uses a couple of parameters for adding vertical space between rows of subfloats.

Use `\captionsetup{farskip=0pt}` where you want the space to disappear. Note that I have reduced the code to a MWE, add back the packages and settings you need.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering{}\rule{0.5\textwidth}{0.5\textwidth}%
\caption{Single figure nicely aligned}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}[tp]
\captionsetup{farskip=0pt}% <--- no gap at the top
\centering
\subfloat[First subfigure]{\rule{.49\textwidth}{5cm}}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Second subfigure]{\rule{.49\textwidth}{5cm}}%

\caption{Group of figures with ugly gap on top}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]